# how can I handle exception in my api in lumen?

Tags: logging, storage, lumen

I want to create a logging section in the lumen app.
That way, every day in Lumen, I create a file named the same day (date time be file name) in storage and save the contents of my own logs.
please guide me.
Do I need scheduling for it?

Comment: Why not use the built in logging functionality of lumen?

Comment: Please help for this work.

Comment: First see the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging if you have a clear question with an example of what you have tried so far and what did not work we can take a look at how to fix that specific problem. Right now your question is too generic